# Can css3 take background-image in @keyframes fading or what method to use?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background fade-in swapping with another image, like fading in colors like :

```
animation: fading 35s infinite;
-webkit-animation: fading 35s infinite;
font-family:siteFont;
}
@keyframes fading {
    width:100%;
0%   {background-image:url (red;}
25%  {background: yellow; }
50%  {background: blue; }
75%  {background: green;}
100% {background: red;}
}
```

or is there another method with css to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/myTerminal/U32gf/

I just kept on changing `background-image`.

Besides, the CSS that you have put here is broken badly.